# Wikitude AR.RelativeLocation, how to increase gyroscope precision?

Tags: android, gyroscope, wikitude

I'm using Wikitude (on Android with the Javascript APIs) to show a transparent video inside of the AR experience. I don't have a marker on which putting my video. That video has its coordinates (relative to the user's position) and I want to place it on an exact position so that the user can see it when its device is pointing towards that direction.

In order to do that I used an AR.RelativeLocation object and placed a VideoDrawable on a particular position.

```
// the location
var location = new AR.RelativeLocation(null, 5, 5, 0);

// the video
var video = new AR.VideoDrawable("assets/transparentVideo.mp4", 5, {
    scale: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
        z: 1
    },
    isTransparent: true,
    onLoaded: this.worldLoaded
});
video.play(0) // the video starts immediately

// the GeoObject showing the video
var obj = new AR.GeoObject(location, {
    drawables: {
       cam: [video]
    }
});
```

The problem is that the video is not stable at all. When I turn my device I see the video approximately on its position but it's not fixed: it moves following my camera movements for a while as if it would placed by using the movement sensor rather than the gyroscope. Is there a possibility to stabilize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikitude Android SDK is not using the gyroscope at the moment but a combination of accelerometer and compass to calculate the orientation. There is also no method to change the accuracy. What you can try is calibrating your compass like described here: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6145351?hl=en or here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-can-i-calibrate-the-compass-on-my-phone and try to keep a distance to things that can influence the compass accuracy like other electrical devices.

Comment: The doc says, for the property [hardware.sensors.enabled](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/Reference/JavaScript%20API/classes/hardware.html#property_sensors.enabled): *Controls if the sensors are active or not. Sensors include GPS, mangetometer, accelerometer and **gyroscope**.* 

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, this is an issue in the documentation. This only applies to iOS where the gyro is used.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you plan to use it in the future on devices equipped with a gyroscope?

Comment: We have gyro support on our feature list, but not on our roadmap yet, so we can’t provide any details on if/when this feature will be implemented.

Comment: Does the gyro has been supported on Android? Or it is still used only on iOS?

Comment: The gyroscope is now used on android when available.

Comment: Thanks! :-) Please update the documentation also, if possible